# Hover over an Image, change another Image's z-index

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index

I have a webpage with 6 small images and 1 big images in the center (which is really 6 layers, each contains 1 images), just like this: http://jsbin.com/onujiq/1/; I've set the z-index property of all center images to (-1). What I'm trying to do is when I hover over 1 of the 6 small images, the respectively image will appear as the big images in the center (by change the respectively center image's z-index to 5 - for example) ; but no matter how I try, It's doesn't work as what I want. Please help me with this (I only use CSS); thank you in advance !

PS: another confusing problem when i test about hover is when I use this code:

```
#img3:hover + #img4{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

it does work, but when i use this:

```
#img3:hover + #img5{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

it doesn't ! I still dont' know what is the big different between #img4 & #img5 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yy9Rr/

Your solution was close, but you need to change it from

```
#img3:hover + #img4{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

to use the `~`, to give something like

```
#img3:hover ~ #imgCenter3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

`a + b` says any `b` element immediately following element `a`

`a ~ b` says any `b` element that is a following sibling of `a`, not necessarily immediately adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("img3").onmouseover = function() {
document.getElementById("img4").style.opacity = ".2";
document.getElementById("img5").style.opacity = ".2";
}
```